# Raster calculation with multiple rasters using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, error-000539, error-010240

I have three rasters:

- Raster1: resolution 25x25, floating point. Value of "1" when it is true, value of -9999 when it is false (only this two values)
- Raster2: resolution 25x25, floating point. Only integer values from 194 to 1738
- Raster3: resolution 25x25, floating point. Decimal values are stored too, from -2544,81 to 941,66

All the rasters have the same CRS and are in TIFF format.

What I want to do is to create a fourth raster like this:

```
If Raster1 =1, then Raster2 (true statement), else Raster3 (false statement)
```

I tried this in ArcGis 10.3 Raster Calculator:

```
Con("Raster1" == 1,"Raster2","Raster3")
```

But I get this error:

```
Con(Raster(r"Raster1") == 1,Raster(r"Raster2"),Raster(r"Raster3"))
ERROR 000539: Error running expression: rcexec() 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<expression>", line 1, in <module>
File "<string>", line 8, in rcexec
RuntimeError: ERROR 010240: Could not save raster dataset to F:\folder\step13 with output format GRID.

Failed to execute (RasterCalculator).
```

I tried the same thing using Python:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
env.workspace = "F:/folder"
Ras1 = Raster("Raster1")
Ras2 = Raster("Raster2")
Ras3 = Raster("Raster3")
outCon = Con((Ras1==1),Ras2, Ras3)
outCon.save = ("F:/folder/out")
```

But I get this error:

```
RuntimeError: ERROR 000875: Output raster: C:\xxx\xxx\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\ifthe_ras's workspace is an invalid output workspace.
```

I'm stuck. I cannot understand what's wrong with my raster calculations.

Comment: Try saving it as F:\folder\step13.tif.

Comment: @HDunn using the backslashes and adding the .tif results in the same error as above (modifying it in the Python code)

Comment: @Vale - Not tested but for the QGIS Raster Calculator, try `(('Raster1@1' = 1) * 'Raster2@1') + (('Raster1@1' != 1) * 'Raster3@1')`

Comment: @joseph it worked at 90% now I have to understand what went wrong

Comment: Does the name of the output raster exceed 13 characters? Esri GRID format can accept up to 13 characters file name.

Comment: @ahmadhanb no it doesn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the same formula as yours and it worked without any problem:

I used ERDAS Imagine Format (.img) for my input and output raster calculation to avoid the limitation of 13 characters in ESRI GRID format, so I can give a name longer than 13 characters.

[image]

AS you can see above the RasterCalc which is the output is already calculated and loaded in the available layers to use in the future.

Here is the input formula:

```
Con("Elev.img" == 1,"Soil_CC.img","Soil_PP.img")
```

So I think the problem - based on the message you received - is related to the name of the output file which might be exceeding the 13 characters. to avoid that add an extension such as `.img` or `.tif` in the output file name.

Comment: The name of the output doesn't exceed 13 characters, but the input rasters yes. I'm gonna try to reduce the input files names

Comment: The problem was the name of the INPUT files, not the output one. And forcing the output with the .tif extension worked. So what have I done: renamed the input rasters to have less than 13 characters and forced the output to be  a .tif file

Comment: Glad it worked :)